# How to use filter in dplyr to find values in muliple columns without using '|'

Tags: r

I want to use the 'dplyr' package in order to return rows in a data frame that contain some numeric or character values in any of the columns. For example,

```
> set.seed(1)
> mydf <- data.frame(matrix(abs(round(rnorm(200), 1)), nrow = 20))
> mydf
    X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8  X9 X10
1  0.6 0.9 0.2 2.4 0.6 0.6 0.5 1.9 0.4 1.2
2  0.2 0.8 0.3 0.0 0.1 0.0 1.3 1.2 0.2 1.0
3  0.8 0.1 0.7 0.7 1.2 0.9 0.2 1.7 1.1 0.2
4  1.6 2.0 0.6 0.0 1.5 0.2 0.2 0.5 0.9 1.5
5  0.3 0.6 0.7 0.7 0.6 0.7 0.1 1.1 0.6 0.5
6  0.8 0.1 0.7 0.2 0.3 1.8 0.7 0.8 2.2 0.2
7  0.5 0.2 0.4 1.8 1.1 0.7 0.1 2.1 0.3 1.5
8  0.7 1.5 0.8 1.5 0.3 0.9 0.0 0.0 1.4 0.8
9  0.6 0.5 0.1 0.2 0.4 0.4 0.7 1.3 0.1 0.4
10 0.3 0.4 0.9 2.2 0.3 1.7 0.3 1.6 0.2 0.9
11 1.5 1.4 0.4 0.5 0.5 0.6 0.1 0.5 2.3 0.2
12 0.4 0.1 0.6 0.7 1.2 0.5 0.6 0.0 0.1 0.4
13 0.6 0.4 0.3 0.6 1.2 1.4 0.5 0.3 0.5 0.7
14 2.2 0.1 1.1 0.9 0.7 0.7 1.5 0.9 0.1 0.8
15 1.1 1.4 1.4 1.3 1.6 0.2 0.3 1.5 0.3 1.2
16 0.0 0.4 2.0 0.3 0.6 0.4 1.5 1.1 0.0 1.0
17 0.0 0.4 0.4 0.4 1.3 0.3 0.3 1.0 0.8 1.4
18 0.9 0.1 1.0 0.0 0.6 0.3 0.5 0.6 2.1 1.0
19 0.8 1.1 0.6 0.1 1.2 0.5 0.7 1.4 1.0 0.4
20 0.6 0.8 0.1 0.6 0.5 0.2 0.1 1.9 1.2 0.4
```

While I can filter rows conditional on a single column as

```
> mydf %>% filter(X1 %in% c(1.5, 0.2))
   X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8  X9 X10
1 0.2 0.8 0.3 0.0 0.1 0.0 1.3 1.2 0.2 1.0
2 1.5 1.4 0.4 0.5 0.5 0.6 0.1 0.5 2.3 0.2

> mydf %>% filter(X2 %in% c(1.5, 0.2))
   X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8  X9 X10
1 0.5 0.2 0.4 1.8 1.1 0.7 0.1 2.1 0.3 1.5
2 0.7 1.5 0.8 1.5 0.3 0.9 0.0 0.0 1.4 0.8
```

I would like to filter rows based on all columns in the data without using the '|' as below.

```
> mydf %>% filter(X1 %in% c(1.5, 0.2) | X2 %in% c(1.5, 0.2) | ...)
```

Comment: Do you mean something like `mydf[rowSums(sapply(mydf, `%in%`, c(1.5, 0.2))) > 0, ]`?

Comment: There should be backticks around the `%in%`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can do this with base R with `rowSums` and `%in%` instead of loading a package, like this:

```
> mydf[rowSums(sapply(mydf, `%in%`, c(1.5, 0.2))) > 0, ]
    X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8  X9 X10
1  0.6 0.9 0.2 2.4 0.6 0.6 0.5 1.9 0.4 1.2
2  0.2 0.8 0.3 0.0 0.1 0.0 1.3 1.2 0.2 1.0
3  0.8 0.1 0.7 0.7 1.2 0.9 0.2 1.7 1.1 0.2
4  1.6 2.0 0.6 0.0 1.5 0.2 0.2 0.5 0.9 1.5
6  0.8 0.1 0.7 0.2 0.3 1.8 0.7 0.8 2.2 0.2
7  0.5 0.2 0.4 1.8 1.1 0.7 0.1 2.1 0.3 1.5
8  0.7 1.5 0.8 1.5 0.3 0.9 0.0 0.0 1.4 0.8
9  0.6 0.5 0.1 0.2 0.4 0.4 0.7 1.3 0.1 0.4
10 0.3 0.4 0.9 2.2 0.3 1.7 0.3 1.6 0.2 0.9
11 1.5 1.4 0.4 0.5 0.5 0.6 0.1 0.5 2.3 0.2
14 2.2 0.1 1.1 0.9 0.7 0.7 1.5 0.9 0.1 0.8
15 1.1 1.4 1.4 1.3 1.6 0.2 0.3 1.5 0.3 1.2
16 0.0 0.4 2.0 0.3 0.6 0.4 1.5 1.1 0.0 1.0
20 0.6 0.8 0.1 0.6 0.5 0.2 0.1 1.9 1.2 0.4
```